# replacing anchor text with jquery

Tags: jquery, anchor

i have tried using html() and text()  to try change the text of an anchor - but i cant get it to work :(

here is a fiddle to show you -

http://jsfiddle.net/kneidels/GzuLh/

```
      $('#contact-form-send').bind('click',function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();

          $(".button").text('Logging in...');
          $("#mess").delay(2000).fadeIn(400);
          $("#mess").html('<p class="message">Username/Password do not match. Please contact our office for assistance</p>');
           $(".button").text("Submit");

        $("#mess").delay(2000).fadeOut(400);


  });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `.delay()` but lines following it doesnt catch the delay, you need to do the code when the fadeIn is done, to do that just write your `.fadeIn()` code like that :

```
      $("#mess").delay(2000).fadeIn(400, function(){
          $("#mess").html('<p class="message">Username/Password do not match. Please contact our office for assistance</p>');
           $(".button").text("Submit");

        $("#mess").delay(2000).fadeOut(400);

      });
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/GzuLh/3/

Answer (score 1):

Use the `.fadeIn()` CALLBACK

```
$('#contact-form-send').bind('click',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).text('Logging in...');
      $("#mess").delay(2000).fadeIn(400, function(){
          $(this).html('<p class="message">Username/Password do not match. Please contact our office for assistance</p>').delay(2000).fadeOut(400);
          $(".button").text("Submit");
      });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GzuLh/8/